# If domain $A$ of the homomorphism $f$ is a field, and if the range of $f$ has more than one element, then $f$ is injective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, field-theory

This is a question from Pinter's A book of Abstract Algebra:

> If domain A of the homomorphism $f$ is a field, and if the range of
>   $f$ has more than one element, then $f$ is injective.

Here's my attempt:

Claim. If $\text{im} f \ne \{ 0\}$ then $f(1)\ne 0$.

Proof (by contrapositive). Suppose that $f(1)=0$. Then if $x\in A$ then $f(x)= f(x\cdot 1) = f(x)f(1)= f(x)\cdot 0=0$. Hence, $\text{im} f = \{ 0\}$.

To show that $f$ is injective, it is enough to show that $\text{ker} f =\{ 0\}$. Let $x \in \text{ker} f$. Then $f(x)=0$. We claim that $x=0$. Suppose that $x\ne 0$. Then there is an element $x^{-1} \in A$ such that $xx^{-1} = 1$.
Now,
$f(x)=0 \\ \Rightarrow f(x)f(x^{-1}) = 0 \cdot f(x^{-1}) \\ \Rightarrow f(xx^{-1})=0 \\ \Rightarrow f(1)=0$

Which is a contradiction!

Thus, $\text{ker} f =\{ 0\}$ . This completes the proof.

Is this okay or am I missing something? I was wondering if there was some easier way to do this.

Comment: Are you familiar with ideals? If yes, then you can use the fact that a field has only two ideals, namely the field itself or the zero ideal. Since kernels are ideals, so for a homomorphism from a field, either the kernel is just $\{0\}$ or whole $\Bbb{F}$. With the range being non-trivial, kernel has to be $\{0\}$, hence injective.

Comment: @AnuragA  I did prove that fields have no nontrivial ideals (as an exercise in my book). I guess I need to verify that kernel are ideals. However, is my aforementioned proof okay?

Comment: Yes your proof is good.